# Login and Logout in curl?

Tags: php, curl

I login to my account with this code.
    http://www.mywebsite.com/login.php';

```
$postVars = 'username=myuser&password=1234'; 
$tmpfname = 'cookie.txt'; 
$page = '/login.php'; 
$headers = array( 
        "POST ".$page." HTTP/1.1", 
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", 
        "Accept: */*", 
        "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5", 
        "Cache-Control: no-cache", 
        "Referer: http://www.mywebsite.com/", 
        "Content-length: ".strlen($postVars), 
        "Pragma: no-cache", 
        "Connection: keep-alive", 
        "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest", 
        "Cache-Control: no-cache" 
    ); 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVars); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmpfname); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmpfname); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
$run = curl_exec($ch); 
$info = curl_getinfo($ch); 

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

After Login,I want to visit http://mywebsite.com/profile.php and http://example.com/home.php,and Logout by visiting http://mywebsite.com/logout.php

What should I do? Do you have an example?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some [additional research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and if you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Thank you.I don't know what should I do really,So I need to know your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to **maintain a session in CURL**(just like browser). so that you can visit other pages where access control is activated.

For this what you can do is, save the cookies in a file , while login. and use that cookies while visiting other pages. because generally **session is maintained via cookies**.

If you use CURLOPT_COOKIE_FILE and CURLOPT_COOKIE_JAR then curl will read/write the cookies from/to a file.

So add these 3 lines to all the curl queries.

```
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", 'cookiename');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
```